# How to link to an .ipa file (over the air ios app installation) using django and STATIC_URL?

Tags: django, ipa, ota, django-staticfiles

I have a django server set up in development. It is basically the simplest "app store" you can imagine. I can now finally serve up static images using STATIC_URL as the prefix.

I however have failed to be able to enable over the air installation of my .ipa file.

When I click on my link on my iPhone or iPad, I get a 404 error, which leads me to think that the path to my .ipa is incorrect.  Except that I think that my path is correct :>

Can anyone please point me to what the magic path needs to be?

Thank you!

Inside my django template, all I do is provide a link to the app like so:

Neither of the following work:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://192.168.1.109:8000/appstore/static/binaries/coolRunner.plist">Cool Runner </a>

<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url={{STATIC_URL}}binaries/coolRunner.plist">Cool Runner </a>

<a href="{{STATIC_URL}}binaries/coolRunner.plist">Cool Runner </a>
```

So the third try, links to my plist and it IS found, but when I click on it in mobile Safari on my iPHone it just displays the contents of the pList.  I am supposed to link to the pList and not the .ipa, right?

```
 <a href="{{STATIC_URL}}binaries/coolRunner.ipa">Cool Runner </a>
```

The fourth try (directly above where I link to the ipa) prompts me to download the ipa, and then mobile Safari offers to let me open the link in Evernote, or a few other apps.  Not exactly what I want.

In the exact same template, for sanity checks, I provide a link to an mp3 and an iphone configuration profile, which both DO work (clicking on the iphone configuration profile link does launch the iPhone's settings app and asks me to install the config profile correctly)

```
<a href="{{STATIC_URL}}binaries/test.mp3">cool song</a>

<a href="{{STATIC_URL}}binaries/coolRunner.mobileconfig>Cool Runner Configuration Profile</a>
```

Could there be a problem with my actual ipa file, as in, maybe it is not provisioned right?  I used XCode 4.5 and archived it, and followed the dead simple wizard, distributed it for enterprise/ad-hoc deployment, code-signed it with my identity (I have all the privileges except that I am not the Team Agent, but I am an admin), and filled out the form that requires an App URL (which I said to be `http://192.168.1.109:8000/appstore/static/binaries/coolRunner.plist`)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean. Can you give me more details? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well the one thing I neglected, is the way to do it:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://192.168.1.109:8000/static/binaries/coolRunner.plist">Cool Runner </a>
```

That works.  For others who may come after me, let me explain that when you have STATIC_URL defined at the default /static/ in django's development server, you locate your static files right off the domain name and port number: (e.g., `http://192.168.1.109:8000/static/captain_obvious.png`)

Please also note that I did NOT have to add a type="application/octet-stream" nor a type="text/xml" either on the development server nor in my  tag. I'd seen some posts that said that you need it, although those posts may have been referring to production.